# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException I am getting this error full log is attached below

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**My code:**

```
package com.webdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class TestWikipedia {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.com");
     WebElement link;
     link =driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("English"));
     link.click();
     WebElement searchBox;
     searchBox =driver.findElement(By.id("SearchInput"));
     searchBox.sendKeys("Software");
     searchBox.submit();
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     driver.quit();
```

**Error Log:**

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"SearchInput"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 382 milliseconds For documentation on
>   this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
>   System info: host: 'Bharat.local', ip: '192.168.0.7', os.name: 'Mac OS
>   X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_151' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false,
>   handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0, platform=MAC,
>   nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   92c5544c-358d-0444-8c68-ad4d2b834d06
>   *** Element info: {Using=id, value=SearchInput}   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
>     at com.webdriver.TestWikipedia.main(TestWikipedia.java:19) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"SearchInput"} For documentation on this
>   error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
>   System info: host: 'Bharat.local', ip: '192.168.0.7', os.name: 'Mac OS
>   X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_151' Driver info: driver.version: unknown  at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///var/folders/7m/q5ljmg551fjbld41j5z5_x600000gp/T/anonymous2176535614827261367webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
>     at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///var/folders/7m/q5ljmg551fjbld41j5z5_x600000gp/T/anonymous2176535614827261367webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///var/folders/7m/q5ljmg551fjbld41j5z5_x600000gp/T/anonymous2176535614827261367webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///var/folders/7m/q5ljmg551fjbld41j5z5_x600000gp/T/anonymous2176535614827261367webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///var/folders/7m/q5ljmg551fjbld41j5z5_x600000gp/T/anonymous2176535614827261367webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

Comment: Your locator Id might have multiple matches so try using different locators for locating an element.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
searchBox =driver.findElement(By.id("SearchInput"))
```

to

```
searchBox =driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput"))
```

(lowercase "s").

Comment: I have resolved this issues fallow this steps

Comment: Yogesh, you should mark this as the accepted answer, and perhaps also upvote his answer.